# Hudson CI: cannot test grails-app

Tags: testing, grails, continuous-integration, hudson

I've tried in each and every way to test a grails-app using hudson. I've tried testing with maven, I've tried testing with the grails plugin and <strike>I've tried testing with a shell builder</strike> it seems that building via shell is the only thing that works..

Every time I get the same error:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   contains is not valid without active
>   transaction

But If i go to a shell and type

> grails test-app

everything runs fine.
Does anyone have any idea on what's going on?

---

I'm using CentOS with Java 1.6, no slaves, just a simple hudson deploy over Tomcat6.
I've tried both with maven and grails builder, both fail.

---

**Edit**: it seems that if I run both unit and integration tests on the same command (either with grails or with mvn) the integration tests fail always.

Comment: Some context about your setup would help - Hudson version, platform you are using (windows, linux, other), are slaves in use, and so on.   The simpler you can make it, the better.

Comment: How are you testing using Hudson? Are you invoking grails test-app, or are you using the Maven Project configuration.. In the first case: post more details! In the second case: Make Maven work from the commandline first!

Answer (score 0):

Hudson/Jenkins usually just use the command line for executing grails plugins (You should be able to confirm that from the build output). You could probably add a pre build step to dump the environment, so you can see if anything there (or in your own shell) cause it to be fundamentally different.

Otherwise try to log in as the hudson user and find the hudson workspace and repeat the process manually. That has been the easiest way to debug hard problems like this..
regards